# Can you retrieve json data without it being json_encoded in php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am not having any luck but i was wondering if i could grab json data if it is not json encoded server side with php. for example if i were to just echo some data like so:

```
echo '{"subscriptions": [{"subscribe":"'.$subscribe[0].'"},{"subscribe":"'.$subscribe[1].'"},{"subscribe":"'.$subscribe[2].'"},{"subscribe":"'.$subscribe[3].'"},{"subscribe":"'.$subscribe[4].'"}]}';
```

could i still use a jQuery ajax json call to grab the data?

Comment: There are so many ways for the JSON to be completely broken. Use the encoder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That certainly looks ok and should work just fine.

`json_encode()` only makes the process easier as it'd be pretty easy to make a quoting / bracket / brace / square-bracket error when creating the string manually.

I'm guessing you're only asking as `json_encode()` is not available on your server. As an alternative, you could try the component from Zend Framework. This attempts to use `json_encode()` but falls back to a built-in approach when not available.

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.html

Comment: thanks a ton, now i just need to get my each loop to work. thanks again for the quick response and the help!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as long as the echo'd data is valid JSON data

Answer (score 2):

Essentially all that is happening is you are creating a JSON format and creating your own encoder. But you will need to post your own JSON headers as well. Start your callback PHP file with:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Remember that you will need to take special attention to formatting your JSON otherwise it will break your application.

Answer (score 1):

I believe as long as you send our the proper server header indicating it's JSON content `Content-Type: application/json` it should be good.

Whats wrong with using PHP's `json_encode()`? Are you working with an older version of PHP?

Comment: no i just am using mysqli and its tough to get a prepared queries reuslts into an array. there is no built in function to do so, so i am going about it a different way

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it's not recommended. You should use `json_encode`. If you have problems for transforming your object first, you can do it like this:

```
$obj = array(
  "subscriptions" => array(
     array("subscribe" => (string)$subscribe[0]),
     array("subscribe" => (string)$subscribe[1]),
     array("subscribe" => (string)$subscribe[2]),
     array("subscribe" => (string)$subscribe[3]),
  )
);
echo json_encode($obj);
```

Cheers